# How to format popups in R (vistime/plotly plot)

Tags: r, plotly, vistime

I have the following example of a plot built using vistime/plotly. I'm wondering how to format the popups?  I have not been able to find any documentation of how to do this, but maybe I'm just overlooking something.

For example, I'd love to change the background color, width, font, line spacing, etc. of the popups.  I'm sure this is possible to do using css/html, but I'm unaware how to do this in the R environment.

```
curr_year <- 2017
data <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color
                       Phase 1,Project,2016-12-22,2016-12-23,#c8e6c9
                       Phase 2,Project,2016-12-23,2016-12-29,#a5d6a7
                       Phase 3,Project,2016-12-29,2017-01-06,#fb8c00
                       Phase 4,Project,2017-01-06,2017-02-02,#DD4B39
                       Room 334,Team 1,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#DEEBF7
                       Room 335,Team 1,2016-12-28,2017-01-05,#C6DBEF
                       Room 335,Team 1,2017-01-05,2017-01-23,#9ECAE1
                       Group 1,Team 2,2016-12-22,2016-12-28,#E5F5E0
                       Group 2,Team 2,2016-12-28,2017-01-23,#C7E9C0
                       3-200,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                       3-330,category 1,2016-12-25,2016-12-25,#1565c0
                       3-223,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-225,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-226,category 1,2016-12-28,2016-12-28,#1565c0
                       3-226,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                       3-330,category 1,2017-01-19,2017-01-19,#1565c0
                       1-217.0,category 2,2016-12-27,2016-12-27,#90caf9
                       4-399.7,moon rising,2017-01-13,2017-01-13,#f44336
                       8-831.0,sundowner drink,2017-01-17,2017-01-17,#8d6e63
                       9-984.1,birthday party,2016-12-22,2016-12-22,#90a4ae
                       F01.9,Meetings,2016-12-26,2016-12-26,#e8a735
                       Z71,Meetings,2017-01-12,2017-01-12,#e8a735
                       B95.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735
                       T82.7,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735")

data <- as.data.frame(data)                               
p <- vistime(data)
pb <- plotly_build(p)
p
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation on Plotly page](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-hoverlabel) the following is possible:

Example:

```r
plotly::style(p, hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "purple", 
                                   bordercolor = "green", 
                                   font = list(color = "white", 
                                               family = "Arial", 
                                               size = 40)))
```

[image]